# Observable.of is not a function with correct import

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

I'm having a problem with the import of the "of" method for observable in angular 6, even with a fresh project install, all updated packages, I still get the error.
So, i made a small project

this is the service giving

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TableRow } from './table-row';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestTableService {

  private testData : TableRow[] = [
    {id:1, name:'pi', value:3.14},
    {id:2, name:'euler', value:2.71},
    {id:3, name:'Feigenbaum constant', value:2.50290},
    {id:4, name:'Mills constant', value:1.30637},
    {id:5, name:'one', value:1},
    {id:6, name:'square root of 2', value:1.41421}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  public getData() : Observable<TableRow[]>
  {
    return Observable.of(this.testData);
  }
}
```

this is the component using it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestTableService } from './../test-table.service';
import { TableRow } from './../table-row';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-table',
  templateUrl: './test-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-table.component.css']
})
export class TestTableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableData : TableRow[] = [];

  constructor(private testTable : TestTableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testTable.getData()
      .subscribe(table => this.tableData = table);
  }

}
```

Notice the imports are all the same as the other questions

[image: the error I get]

the projects package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-table-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

[image: the angular cli version output]

what could be the problem?

Comment: Try changing `Observable.of` to just `of`.

Comment: Excellent! Posted as an answer.

Comment: @BigFilhao you can check my answer with the example of pipe .. it's mandatory now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rxjs 6 (or angular 6 ) the import path and the Observable creation methods have changed . For example -

`Observable.fromEvent` has now become `fromEvent` .
`Observable.of` has become `of`, similarly for `interval` (which was `Observable.interval` before). They are no longer static methods of Observable class.
 Another big change is the use of `pipe` operator is now mandatory . 
 For example in order to use `map` operator on an Observable and then use `subscribe` on it we have to follow the below syntax now -

`Observable.pipe(map((val) => ...)).subscribe();`

We can add multiple comma separated  operators inside `pipe` which will be executed from left to right in order.

Check these links for more reference :

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Answer (score 10):

In `rxjs` 6.x, `of` is no longer a static function on `Observable`.

So, instead of calling `Observable.of(…)`, you just need to call `of(…)`.

See [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for this and other migration information when going from `rxjs` 5.x to 6+.